# Connection string has quotation mark, how to pass it to SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, localdb

I have created a `LocalDB` database in my project and its connection string is :

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="E:\Projects\visual studio 2013\Projects\sqlce\mydb.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

How should I pass it to `SqlConnection()`?

Note that it has an address within quotation marks. Have I done anything wrong?

I guess even if I program it correctly it won't work in another computer which doesn't have that `.mdf` file in that exact place. Isn't it so?

How can I have a program with a portable database so I can easily publish my pp?

Comment: Put your connection string in app.config--related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918912/app-config-connection-string -- or escape your quotes -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072580/how-can-i-escape-quotes-within-a-string-that-is-stored-in-a-variable-in-c-sharp

Comment: SQL Server (which is what uses the `.mdf` file) is a **server-based** database system - it can definitely not be considered a *portable* database. You need to either **install** SQL Server (the core engine) on a remote system, or have access to a LAN with a SQL Server instance running somewhere on that LAN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the mdf file to your solution and and change the property "Copy to Output Directory" to Copy Always. Don't hardcode the mdf file path in connection string. Add the connection string in app.config or web.config file like below:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then you can access the connection string in your C# code as below:

```
string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString()
```

If you face any error regarding accessing the mdf file, the you can set the DataDirectory in your C# code using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

you can  access by

```
connString =rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
```

[More about connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring);
```

or you can go in this way like

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```